# check if the combination of values from different fields in a table exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing a stored procedure where I need to check some constraints before inserting the value.

the combination of **name, sex and HQ_code** should not exists in the table. I am using `select 1` for this constraint check. If the combination is not present then only execute the insert statement and if the combination already exists print message. Please see the comment part in the code. But can not proceed further.

```
create proc_set_ref_staff
    @name       varchar(50),
    @sex        varchar(1),
    @hq_code    varchar(4),
    @out_result varchar(500)   output

as
begin
    begin try

        select 1 from tbl_ref_staff where name = @name and sex = @sex and hq_code = @hq_code;
        --- if the combination exists set @out_result = 'already exists'

        --- how can I write if the above combination not exists then only execute insert statement
        --- insert into tbl_ref_staff values (@name, @sex, @hq_code)

    end try
    begin catch
        set @out_result = error_message();
    end catch;

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking something like that?

```
 IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_ref_staff WHERE name = @name AND sex = @sex AND hq_code = @hq_code;)
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tbl_ref_staff VALUES (@name, @sex, @hq_code)
 END
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. how to print the message `@out_result = 'already exists'` if the value already exist. Please can you edit your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if exists(select 1 from ...) 
begin 
...
end
```

or you can use syntax

```
if (select count(1) from ..) > 0 
begin 
...
end
```